# What command to force dd output to a fixed width of 90 characters?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, dd-wrt

using:
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

`dd --version`
dd (coreutils) 8.32

Background:

- re-purpose a disk = objective
- some script is being developed
- some script will delete first 128 MB of disk: `dd` urandom, `dd` zero
- some script will delete last  128 MB of disk: `dd` urandom, `dd` zero
- command below shows terminal status of disk first 1024 bytes
- command below shows terminal status of disk last  1024 bytes
- sudo wxHexEditor -- confirms terminal output

Question:
How to tell dd to limit screen output to 90 characters wide?

1024 characters wide is the block of data
_111 characters was screen width
__90 characters is desired output width.

Why 90 characters wide for Terminal output?
Because 90 characters wide matches screen of wxHexEditor 0.24

script and function:

```
d2d=sd_   # sda or sdb or sdc ... d2d=disk2display or disk2delete 
num1=1    # used twice in function below ... 
clear 
 
function105_firstbytes_lastbytes(){
tput setaf  8
sudo dd if=/dev/$d2d bs=512 count=1 skip=0 status=none                                                     |hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"'  #First_bytes  
echo   
tput setaf 12
echo "                                             above First bytes, Below Last bytes" ; 
tput setaf  8
sudo dd if=/dev/$d2d bs=512 count=$num1 skip=$(($(sudo blockdev --getsz "/dev/$d2d" ) -$num1)) status=none |hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"'  #Last_bytes   
}
 
function105_firstbytes_lastbytes   #call_above_function
```

The current output = 111 characters wide.
The desired output = _90 characters wide.
The desired output would look like, see below:

```
fab800108ed0bc00b0b800008ed88ec0fbbe007cbf0006b90002f3a4ea21060000bebe073804750b83c61081aa
fe0775f3eb16b402b001bb007cb2808a74018b4c02cd13ea007c0000ebfe000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003a17e5ab0000007f0280
83fec2ffffff00001af1e50e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000055aa
                                             above First bytes, Below Last bytes
ddf5454fc7754665c43e2dc420c4edf6a5096e490bf3efdd00259d5712e2c73250916c64f822874eb5db155b77
371ab1bcd1e60a2331b4df1f2b64b49ed8270236481a79f4c48b7c9f04bf8acc8dcd7ba80a2f8052da27e1d400
7edea887cc579848edbb87ef260fee4a8e2424e706a475f6e565f010dd07de053bcaed7f4c449365d3b0d8906e
fa10e4cb9263bb3065ef9862db4ca7ba3d03e0835edc8865474ef088390a68ca67daf7ce57215e02d9e90e6042
d2ef66c1290fc55730e076645c55ffc7c15fdae24678a6a6fdb69ab66c0299a4d2e1dd342f1e25ee3277634080
ceb7b5068633592ec5d061cbf0cac42d02511362393d49c5d6c7b056843881fa634a1036cef09603c60caea6cc
da0373467f929e9fd358adf8e4aa5502b4847b2d9f1589c4de13adeaac7dedce9963b9e0740ee6938d62c1352a
4e80244446b85d43ef9e5e9180cfe15f3f1ccc035ef2be506e5bb9114791ef81b7930a2871b22b4cb91a5a1c3e
d90816f5e701e4ac33023a38989caa0231ba84571cccff2ded5c0ab14556b6685e813724167feb6f7eae760fea
61dacd2902dd92695af3c9c35a574e2b9f471d9a64e6589ce44406ab96f4faf1161cb5431c3ef35c61a02b33ca
ed1200a35c765504362dcf2bae73ca7be2f34fcc55da77005f802a7af28932c2ca2d78b846db4370edeea8b859
1d3501933c4062f9acd5ddc8e31223edf3
```

.

sidebar Question:
Why does `dd` command `bs=512` output 1024 bytes?
Why double?  512 x 2 = 1024 bytes
from `man dd`
`bs`=BYTES -- read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time
(default: 512); overrides ibs and obs

sidebar Answer:
Why 892 bytes altered not 446 bytes? 446x2=892 bytes
[Why 892 bytes altered not 446 bytes? 446x2=892 bytes](https://superuser.com/questions/1815380/why-892-bytes-altered-not-446-bytes-446x2-892-bytes)
showing 8 bits (i.e. a single byte) in
hexadecimal format requires 2 characters – Jaromanda

.

What command to force `dd` output to a
fixed width of 90 characters?

--

Comment: Side query, Is this script only ever running on HDDs? Writing random data and then zeroing blocks on an SSD is borderline useless as the write leveller won't explicitly use the same flash cells and is just wasting writes compared to just running TRIM on those zones.

Comment: "*Why does dd command bs=512 output 1024 bytes?*" - Sounds like you're confusing a byte with the *representation* of its value using hexadecimal characters on a terminal screen.

Comment: Also answering your side question of why one byte is shown as two characters: it is because you are not showing the data in its raw format. A single byte is eight bits of data. In binary it would be seen as 8 characters 10101010. In decimal you need 3 characters as a byte can represent any number up to 255. In hex you need two characters to represent a byte. You are seeing a representation of the byte, not the bytes themselves.

Comment: You're not seeing the output of `dd`, you're seeing the output of `hexdump`. A tool that may help is `fold -w`.

Comment: Yes,  Applying ```fold``` answer to be 90 characters wide ```|fold -w 90```   
we have desired result,

Comment: Mokubai typed 
```"Is this script only ever running on HDDs?"``` 
Both HDD & SDD. 
```"zeroing blocks on an SSD is borderline useless"``` 
But in some cases data remains on disk to be re-purposed.  
So zero 128 MB got rid of remaining data.  
The script being tested does many things, in short: 
1. Make Partition Table 2. Make Partition 3. Choose filesystem:  
```ext4``` ntfs ```vfat``` exfat. 
Did above step 1 & 2, then ```lsblk``` and 
sometimes filesystem data remained from previous disk use 
like: ```FSTYPE``` ```LABEL``` thus 
zero 128 MB got rid of data, bird turd on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Kamil typed:
You're not seeing the output of dd,
you're seeing the output of hexdump.
A tool that may help is fold -w. –

.

Applying `fold` answer to be 90 characters wide `|fold -w 90`
we have desired result,
change 2 lines in above script to be:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/$d2d bs=512 count=1 skip=0 status=none                                                     |hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' |fold -w 90   #First_bytes  

sudo dd if=/dev/$d2d bs=512 count=$num1 skip=$(($(sudo blockdev --getsz "/dev/$d2d" ) -$num1)) status=none |hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' |fold -w 90   #Last_bytes
```